# Discover wants to install older kernel version

Tags: kernel, discover-software-center

I have recently installed Kubuntu 21.04, and upgraded the kernel manually to version 5.14 because the wifi adapter was not recognized first and I read in a forum that it has been solved in the new kernel (it works now indeed).
If I understand correctly, the updater program Discover wants to install earlier kernel versions now, i.e. Linux headers generic 5.11.0.34.36 -> 5.11.0.36.38 etc.
How to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you have not uninstalled the older kernel. Discover wants to update that older kernel. It would not overwrite your kernel 5.14.

If you want, you can uninstall that package, but it is a good idea to keep one extra kernel for safety.